# matlab string array to python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, string, matlab

I have an array of strings in Matlab and I want to use it with python. I tried to do the same process as for numeric arrays i.e.

```
np_array = scipy.io.loadmat(mat_array)
```

which works with numeric data.

But when I try to use a string array like

```
mat_str_array = [“This”, “is”, “a”, “string”]
```

I get an error/warning stating

> cannot be transformed using the same method

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: String arrays are quite new to MATLAB, it's possible that this has not yet been implemented in Python MAT-file readers. Try instead to save as a cell array of character vectors (this are the old-style string arrays). `{'this','is','a','string'}`.

Comment: Thank you, Cris!

Comment: It does not work with cell arrays either.

Comment: It is supposed to: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html#matlab-cell-arrays

Comment: It works with numbers but not with the strings.

Comment: Okay so, {’this’} works but {“that”} does not. single quote string works not the double quote strings

Comment: Indeed. Double quote strings are the new `string` type, single quote strings are the old `char` vector type. The new string type is quite new, I'm not surprised it's not yet implemented in outside tools.

Comment: Once again, thank Cris

Comment: I opened a feature request on github. let's see if we can get support implemented.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12408